# Volatile Table "Variables" in Teradata

Tags: performance, subquery, teradata, temp-tables

I am using a volatile table in Teradata since it's the only way to get *variable* functionality.  I use it for start and end dates, which then get used in subqueries.  I do this so there only needs to be one place to change a date.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE MyTable AS
(
    SELECT
    DATE as runDate,
    runDate - 30 as startDate,
    runDate -1 endDate
) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (runDate)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

This allows the volatile table to stay around until my session ends or I modify it.
I then use it in something like this

```
 SELECT
 myAVG
 from
 (
    SELECT 
    AVERAGE(columnName) as myAVG
    FROM
    WHERE readingDate > MyTable.startDate
    AND readingDate < MyTable.enddDate
 ) a
```

What I have noticed is that using a volatile table *variable* is noticeably **slower** than if I use the dates directly

```
WHERE readingDate > DATE-30
AND readingDate < DATE-1
```

which I would not have expected.

Before people start saying : "Why don't you just calculate the average in the main query?", I'm using this for illustrative purposes, and there may be several different subqueries in practice.

Is there something I'm missing in using *variables* in this way?

Comment: Without seeing an EXPLAIN plan or more concrete example queries, I would suggest making the primary index unique. A cross join of a single row table in a query should not be appreciably slower. Alternatively you could try a WITH clause (CTE). If you have more evidence that you can share, it would be helpful.

Comment: Several years ago I wrote a blog article about that topic: https://downloads.teradata.com/blog/dnoeth/2011/03/global-and-session-level-parameters-in-sql In TD 16+ the QueryBand is finally working, before you can use the View approach

Comment: @dnoeth +1 Nice blog article. If you change your comment to an Answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @dnoeth I would say that is pretty brilliant.